# Pycharm нажал на сочетание клавиш и теперь бесит камандная строка

Tags: pycharm, мышь, курсор

В общем, частенько обращался к консоли пайчарма и нажал КАКОЕ-ТО сочетание клавиш, что сперва у меня отказывалась работать консоль вообще, а теперь, если наводить на текст в этой консоли, то курсор мыши не меняется. Ну вот что бы выделить текст, при наведении курсора - курсор меняется и похож на букву I, а в консоли пайчарма - не меняется. Кто знает как вернуть, а то уже глаз дёргается???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может скриншот добавите к вопросу?

Comment: А как сюда добавлять скрины?

Comment: @Игорь есть кнопка добавления картинки в редакторе вопроса. Просто вставка через ctrl+v в принципе тоже работает.

Comment: нажимаете на [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1532620/edit) под вопросом и там в редакторе увидите кнопку вставки изображения (клавиши `CTRL + G`)

Comment: Спасибо, кнопку править я не нашел на сайте))